# Center only one of two elements in a div?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, centering

I have a simple webpage with a `.topnav` bar and a `.container` with a few elements in it. I am trying to center just the `.container`, not `.topnav`, within the `body` of the page so that it will be vertically centered. However, when I've tried styling `body` with:

```
display:flex;
align-items:center;
justify-content:center;
```

Both the `.topbar` and `.container` are centered. How do I go about centering just the `.container` vertically?

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}

.contact_box {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  height: 20em;
  width: 25em;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 6px #757677;
  float: left;
}

.contact_box img {
  margin-top: 3.3em;
  margin-bottom: 1.2em;
  height: 3em;
  width: 3em;
}

.contact_box h3 {
  color: #6d6d6d;
}

#contact .container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<body id="contact">
  <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
    <a href="index.html">Home</a>
    <a href="about.html">About</a>
    <a href="#" class="selected">Contact</a>
    <a class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row" id="contact_section">
      <div class="contact_box" class="col-md-4">
        <a href="https://github.com/" target="_blank"><img src="resources/github_logo.png" alt="Github"></a>
        <br>
        <h3>GitHub</h3>
      </div>

      <div class="contact_box" class="col-md-4">
        <a href="https://www.linkedin.com" target="_blank"><img src="resources/linkedin_logo.png" alt="LinkedIn"></a>
        <h3>LinkedIn</h3>
      </div>

      <div class="contact_box" class="col-md-4">
        <img src="resources/email_icon.png" alt="EMAIL">
        <h3>Email</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Here's how it looks now:

[image]

Comment: Since you don't want flexbox behavior on your navbar, the simplest solution is probably to not put the navbar in the flexbox.

Comment: It doesn't look like the navbar is in the flexbox. Only the `.container` is set to `display:flex`. I'm confused.

Comment: Ah, you're right @showdev.  I'm confused as well -- Nezdiro can you please clarify what you're asking?  The code snippet you've posted here doesn't match your description of what's going wrong...

Comment: @DanielBeck it doesn't seem to be demonstrated in the code snippet result because the page is not larger than the elements, but on my web page the `contact_section` is being displayed directly under the navbar, not centered vertically on the page. I'll post a screenshot that may help clarify.

Answer (score 3):

Hi to align it vertically  in the middle of the page, set the height of the container to be 100% of the viewport:

```
#contact .container {
    height:100vh;
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
    justify-content:center;
}
```

Comment: I like this answer! The only issue is that now the entire body is greater than the height of viewport, so the boxes only look centered when I scroll down below the navbar. The height of the navbar is 68px and I've tried setting the top of `.container` to `-68px`, but this doesn't seem to effect anything.

Answer (score 1):

I think I see what you're looking for:
header at the top of the page and body below, with body contents centered vertically.

There are three flex systems in my example below:

The first sets up `<body>` as a vertical flex container with two items: `.topnav` and `.container`. The items are justified to the start of the flex container with `justify-content: flex-start` (this is the default anyway) and `.container` is allowed to grow to fill the flex container with `flex-grow:1`.

The second sets up `.container` as a vertical flex container with each `.row` as an item. Items are centered vertically and horizontally with `justify-content: center` and `align-items: center`, respectively.

The third sets up `.row` elements as horizontal flex containers (`flex-direction: row` is the default), with each `.contact_box` as an item. Items are centered horizontally with `justify-content: center`.

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.container {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
}

.contact_box {
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
  border-radius: .5em;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 6px #757677;
  padding: 1em 2em;
  text-align: center;
}

.contact_box h3 {
  margin: .25em 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="topnav">
  <a href="#">Home</a>
  <a href="#">About</a>
  <a href="#" class="selected">Contact</a>
  <a class="icon">&#9776;</a>
</div>

<div class="container">

  <div class="row">

    <div class="contact_box">
      <a href="https://github.com/" target="_blank"><img src="resources/github_logo.png" alt="Github"></a>
      <br>
      <h3>GitHub</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="contact_box">
      <a href="https://www.linkedin.com" target="_blank"><img src="resources/linkedin_logo.png" alt="LinkedIn"></a>
      <h3>LinkedIn</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="contact_box">
      <img src="resources/email_icon.png" alt="EMAIL">
      <h3>Email</h3>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Like this, with each flex system a different color:

[image]

And if you added another `.row`, it might look like this:

[image]